# mostrar datos de una tabla en mysql mediante un jtable

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Mi consulta es la siguiente, tengo 3 tablas relacionadas (alumnos, tutores, parentesco ) y un `jtable` el cual me muestra los datos desde una base de datos `MYSQL`, pero quiero que al hacer click derecho y darle a la opción "Datos Tutor" el cual lo he hecho con un `jmenuitem`, se abra otra ventana con los datos del tutor este es mi código:

```
try {
    String sql = "SELECT p.DescParentezco,t.Apellidos,t.Nombres,t.Telefono,t.Dirección,t.Correo\n"
            + "FROM parentezco p, alumnos a, tutores t\n"
            + "WHERE t.IdParentezco = p.IdParentezco\n"
            + "and t.IdAlumno = a.IdAlumno";

    Statement st = cn.createStatement();
    ResultSet ConsultaTutor = st.executeQuery(sql);

    while (ConsultaTutor.next()) {

        DatosDelTutor.txtparentezcotutor.setText((String) ConsultaTutor.getString(1));
        //DatosDelTutor.txtparentezcotutor.setText(ConsultaTutor.getString(1));
        DatosDelTutor.txtapellidotutor.setText(ConsultaTutor.getString(2));
        DatosDelTutor.txtnombretutor.setText(ConsultaTutor.getString(3));
        DatosDelTutor.txtteletutor.setText(ConsultaTutor.getString(4));
        DatosDelTutor.txtdirectutor.setText(ConsultaTutor.getString(5));
        DatosDelTutor.txtcorrtutor.setText(ConsultaTutor.getString(6));

    }

} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Creo que mi **error** es usar el método `next()` en la clase RS, ya que este metodo te muestra el último dato de la base de datos. ¿Alguno puede ayudarme?

Comment: Que error te da exactamente? ademas next() solo te da el siguiente registro si tienes 10 elementos y el next() lo que hara es que te recorrerla eso 10 registros

Comment: no me da error, es solo que siempre me bota el último registro de la base de datos, y no la fila seleccionada en el Jtable

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres asegurarte de que todo sale correctamente deberías usar el print en consola.

```
System.out.println("MENSAJE");
```

Una vez que ya hayas verificado que sale todo ahora si pasalo al JTable.

Te daré un consejo, el JTable solo agarra valores de tipo PRIMITIVO así que debes convertir los valores por así decirlo COMPUESTOS de tu base de datos en PRIMITIVOS, de esta forma se mostrarán. Si no lo haces así no se mostrarán.

Comment: Trato de intentar con varias formas pero solo me bota los datos del último ingreso en la base de datos, y yo quiero que me de los datos relacionas a la fila seleccionada en el jtable :(